# Make :hover apply to padding as well as main content area

Tags: html, css

I'm adapting some code from a WordPress theme. I've managed to successfully modify the navigation menu to trigger a CSS rollover on `:hover`, but I've run into a strange problem where: the hover only seems to *properly* apply to the main area of the element - rolling over anything inside the padding changes  `background-color` to black and `color` to white as expected, but rolling over the  padding itself triggers only `background-color`, whilst `color` remains black.

How can I change it so that each menu item's rollover is triggered by rolling over its main area *or* its padding?

The navigation menu is contained in something like the following:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
  <ul id="primary-menu" class="primary-menu">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/people/">People</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/mission/">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/donate/">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And here's the CSS that applies to it:

```
.primary-menu>li {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.primary-menu>li a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px;
}

.primary-menu .current-menu-item {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.primary-menu>li:hover, .primary-menu>li:focus, .primary-menu>li:active {                       
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be the solution you are looking for.

Change the rules with the pseudo-classes to this:

```css
.primary-menu>li:hover a,
.primary-menu>li:focus a,
.primary-menu>li:active a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

It says that when a list-item is hovered on, change the background colour and text colour of the hyperlink, not the list item.

Comment: Great solution, I didn't think that was possible, although it's worth noting that this answer is still only half-true. I realised that applying it instead of the old pseudo-class rules was reversing the problem: it would allow the padding to trigger the changing of `color` to `white`, but now the padding's `background-color` had disappeared. I then used some logic to deduce that if each problem was the inverse of the other, then combining them would give me the solution that I needed, and I can confirm this is true. My final code now includes rules for both.